# Riemann Integration, Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function that is integrable on any bounded subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ (but $f$ is not necessarily continuous).  Let $T$ be a positive constant.  We define $F$, the *moving average* of $f$, by

$$F(x) = \int_{x-T}^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Prove that $F$ is uniformly continuous.

Now, I was thinking that I could apply the following theorem to this problem:

Suppose $f\colon [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$.  Define

$$F(t) = \int_a^t f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

for $a \le t \le b$.  Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

But I'm not sure how to get the original lower limit of integration, $x - T$, fixed, as is the case in the above theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ \forall x $   $ F(x+\varepsilon)-F(x) $ $\leq $ $ 2 \varepsilon  M  $ where $|f(x)|< M $ . . .